# API for word definitions

Tags: asp.net, html

i'm trying to implement a little app which basically only hs a label, textbox and a button and when the user enters a word, i want to connect to some online api to retrieve the word's definition and display it in the label. is this possible? all i keep finding is api's related to other stuff on google/other se's. but i have seen this in practice before so i know they are out there, i just don't know where.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/). It has got an API that you can use over the web.

Check it out here: http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/#web

Answer (score 0):

If you search more probably you will find, but let me give you a hint:

You can make a http web request to any website who handles word definitions. You can even search for `"define: " + word` in google and get the response.